# writes out the number of uppercase characters in the user's input

Tags: java, string, uppercase

cant get it to print out number uppercases in the program only starting out. really struggling with the concept of how strings work.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //inputs 
    String Fullname;
    int index;
    
    
    // count starts
    int count = 0;

    // process
    System.out.print(" Please Enter your Name ");
    Fullname = EasyIn.getString();

    for (int i = 0; i < String.length(); i++)
   {
       
       if(Character.isUpperCase(Fullname.charAt(index)));
       count++;
   }  

   System.out.print(" Number of Characters entered: "  );
   
}
```

}

Comment: 1. You need to remove the semicolon at the end of `if(Character.isUpperCase(Fullname.charAt(index)));` and then 2. You can just your count variable `System.out.print(" Number of Characters entered: " + count );`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `String.length`; you have to calculate the length of Fullname
change with `Fullname.length()`